# How to fire a button action created via iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have tried different variants but some why my button doesn't work.

```
        var fileName = "buttonFile.pdf";
        using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4))
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
        {
            doc.Open();
            var button = new PushbuttonField(writer, new Rectangle(300, 300, 330, 330), "Text")
            {
                Text = "Click meh!"
            };
            PdfAppearance theButton = button.GetAppearance();
            theButton.SetAction(PdfAction.JavaScript("app.execMenuItem('SaveAs')", writer), 300, 300, 330, 330);
            writer.AddAnnotation(button.Field);
            doc.Close();
        }`
```

I haven't seen any code of creating buttons via iTextSharp so I tried to use examples from java analogs but I'm not sure that this is the appropriate way to create buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the `Field` instead of the `Appearance`:

```
var f = button.Field;
f.Action = PdfAction.JavaScript("app.execMenuItem('SaveAs')", writer);
writer.AddAnnotation(f);
```

Comment: Thanks. Its wasn't obvious for me that instead of java's get/set methods the properties should be used in c# :) Now you've opened my eyes